# esp32 en and boot wiring for USB UART

Tags: circuit-design, uart, esp32

I am working on my first real PCB design using an ESP32-WROOM-32 N8 and some relays and wanted to skip adding the FTDI and USB from the PCB in favour of exposing the RX/TX/GND/3v3 to be able to use an external USB/TTL.

I believe this is all possible from this Espressif doc:
https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-at/en/latest/esp32/Get_Started/Hardware_connection.html

I've purchased this USB/TTL:
https://littlebirdelectronics.com.au/products/ftdi-ft232rl-usb-to-ttl-serial-converter-adapter-module-5v-and-3-3v

While the USB/TTL has the DTR/CTS I believe I can just use the TX/RX with ESP32's GPIO3 (RX) GPIO1 (TX) and switches for EN and BOOT?

I've put the schematics together but really would love a sanity check on the EN and BOOT switch wiring:

EN/RESET:

[image]

Switch used:https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Tactile-Switches_Yuandi-TS-1093A-A8B3-D2_C499315.html

BOOT:

[image]

Switch used:
https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Tactile-Switches_YIYUAN-YTS-C015-1F_C2910836.html

1. Is this approach sound?
2. Are the switches wired correctly as the schematic diagrams were confusing?
3. Anything missing from these circuits? or a better way of doing this?

Many thanks in advance for your feedback and help!